# Is tar xz safe to use for Ubuntu Full Backups of /?

Tags: backup, tar

I usually shutdown my pc, and use a livecd to make a backup of /, and do:

```
tar cvfp**z** UbuntuComputerBackup.tar.gz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys --exclude=/dev  /
```

I was thinking of now doing *(xz compression instead)*:

```
tar cvfp**J** UbuntuComputerBackup.tar.**xz** --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys --exclude=/dev  /
```

Is this a good idea to now use xz compression? What are do you guys reccomend for full tarball barebones backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is certainly safe. But if it is recommended is a different matter.

Recommending it more depends on your time avaliable and your space avaliable on your backup media.

If you don't have much space but quite a bit of time, use `xz`. It uses a load less space, but quite a bit of time.

If you don't have much time but quite a bit of space, use `gzip`. It uses a lot of space but a lot less time.

If you have something about in the middle of these two extremes, use `bzip2`. It uses a moderate amount of both. You can use

```
tar cvfpj UbuntuComputerBackup.tar.bz2 --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys --exclude=/dev /
```

to use bz2.